# CW Image Optimizer opt-jpg is missing

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, wordpress

I use Wordpress on AWS (CentOS). I tried installing the CW Image Optimizer.

I'm seeing "CW Image Optimizer requires littleutils. You are missing: opt-jpg." error on the plugin settings page.

When I tried, $ which opt-jpg , it throws an error saying,

/usr/bin/which: no opt-jpg (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin)

I also tried to run $ ln -s /usr/local/bin/opt-jpg /usr/bin/opt-jpg

I'm getting the below error,

ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/opt-jpg': File Exists

I already tried yum install libjpeg* but still having the same problem.

Please help me out. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you littleutils is missing, so the course of action seems quite obvious. The [install guide](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cw-image-optimizer/installation/) for CW tells you how to do this on Centos 32 bit. Have you followed the install instructions?

Further searches found a result for 64 bit Centos which may work better than this

```
Log in as the root user.
Enable the rpmforge repository:
cd /usr/local/src/ && wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.i686.rpm && rpm -i rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.i686.rpm
Install dependencies:
yum install gcc libpng libpng-devel gifsicle pngcrush p7zip lzip
Download the latest version of littleutils:
cd  /usr/local/src; wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/littleutils/littleutils/1.0.27/littleutils-1.0.27.tar.bz2?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Flittleutils%2F   
Uncompress littleutils:
tar jxvf littleutils-1.0.27.tar.bz2 && cd littleutils-1.0.27
Configure and install littleutils:
./configure--prefix=/usr && make && make install && make install-extra
```