# littleutils doesn't install opt-jpg

Tags: centos7

I'm running a centOS 7 server. I used the instructions from this post to install littleutils - 
[CW Image Optimizer opt-jpg is missing](https://serverfault.com/questions/763834/cw-image-optimizer-opt-jpg-is-missing)

I received no errors as far as I could tell. The wordpress installation sees that everything installed except for opt-jpg.

I ran this command:
    which opt-jpg 
    /usr/bin/which: no opt-jpg in(/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user1/.local/bin:/home/user1/bin)

I've tried to install version 1.0.27 and 1.0.37. 
I've even tried the symlink fix show here :https://github.com/WPPlugins/cw-image-optimizer and here: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/problem-adding-littleutils.603179/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem I used this command.

```
yum install libjpeg*
```

I found the solution here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/opt-jpg-is-missing/